# How to turn off receiver beans in Spring runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, scheduler, spring-restcontroller

How do you turn off receiver beans in Spring during runtime? For example, I have:

1. 2 Kafka Listener beans.
2. 2 controller beans.
3. 2 scheduler beans.

I need to configure these Beans at the start of an application but only 1 kafka listener and 1 controller can get messages, the other will stay on, but won't get them. After the application receives a control message, I need to turn on all that I have, or turn off all, except for 1 kafka listener and 1 controller.

My current ideas are using:

1. Aspects.
2. Feature toggle.

But I am wondering if Spring can offer me some function for that?